# How to get entity by ancestor key datastore?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I need to get a sub entity from the key of parent. I dont know even if its possible. But what I tried is as following:

```
public function get_service_details(){
     $datastore = new Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient(['projectId' => $this->config->item('google_project_id')]);
     $key = $datastore->key($this->entity_kind);

     $key->ancestor($this->parent_kind, $this->parent_key);
     $server_config_details = $datastore->lookup($key);
     return $server_config_details;
}
```

and

```
public function get_service_details(){
     $datastore = new Google\Cloud\Datastore\DatastoreClient(['projectId' => $this->config->item('google_project_id')]);
     $ancestorKey = $datastore->key($this->parent_kind, $this->parent_key);
     $query = $datastore->query()
        ->kind($this->entity_kind)
        ->hasAncestor($ancestorKey);

     $server_config_details = $datastore->runQuery($query);
     return $server_config_details;
}
```

But in both of the above cases it returned me nothing. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: The first example should throw an error because the key is incomplete (there's no ID/name/identifier in the last path element). The second example should work. Can you give an example of the ancestor key and the key of the entity you are expecting it to return?

Comment: Yes when I tried giving the entity key in the first example like this `$key = $datastore->key($this->entity_kind, $this->entity_key);` it returned me the results but I have a case that in the parent entity (lets say `user`) I don't have the record of the key of its sub entity but I need to get the sub entity (lets say `service`). Now how should I approach it? I need to get the sub entity using its parent key.

Comment: I added an answer. Basically, you need to use a query (like your second example). Rather then constructing `$ancestorKey` as in your example, you can just call `hasAncestor($this->parent_key)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ancestor query to find child entities:

For example, this query:

```
SELECT Floor WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR KEY(Building, 'C')
```

will return all child entities of kind `Floor` of the root entity with kind `Building` and name `C`:

```
[Building:C, Floor:1]
[Building:C, Floor:2]
```

Lookups (as opposed to queries) require that you know the full key ahead of time, so they can't be used to find child entities of a root entity.

Comment: Thanks @Ed. You saved lots of my time :) For more we can take reference from this. (http://qiita.com/idaaki/items/926d0c799e3a328d27b2)